How to retrieve a validator Fields and Index from the Beacon Chain?
I'm working on a stacking / restacking project where I need to call that function:
function verifyWithdrawalCredentials(
    uint64 oracleTimestamp,
    BeaconChainProofs.StateRootProof calldata stateRootProof,
    uint40[] calldata validatorIndices,
    bytes[] calldata validatorFieldsProofs,
    bytes32[][] calldata validatorFields
)
    external

I don't know how can I retrieve my validators infos (validatorIndices, validatorFieldsProofs and validatorFields) from the Beacon Chain.
I found the Beacon Chain doc from the consensus-specs on GitHub:
https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#validator.
But I don't know how to use it...
Does it exist a client where I can ask from these information on-chain or off-chain?
That's been several days I'm stuck on this, would be very grateful of any help!
Thanks!
